# paper-fab stuck in animation on click

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I am trying to swap the icon of a `<paper-fab>` on a click event. But as you can see, the color of `<paper-fab>` changes because of its animation that gets stuck. I started experimenting with requestAnimationFrame.

Code:

```
this.$.editFab.icon = "save";

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.$.editFab.icon = "save";
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! The color change caused of a css rule when paper-fab is focused.
I just added to my css this:

```
paper-fab:focus{
   background: my-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Custom property of `<paper-fab>` with `--paper-fab-keyboard-focus-background`, i.e.

```
paper-fab {
    --paper-fab-keyboard-focus-background: {
      color: --accent-color;
    }
}
```